# Plone: hide search box in home page for anonymous users

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I need to hide the search box in home page, for anonymous users. Anyone know how do it?

[image]

Another request is hide the breadcrumbs, for the same reason.
I've got Plone 4.3.7 with the default interface.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest an simplest way is to hide it by CSS.

If there are no security concerns, your fine with that. 
For this case plone add some special css classes to the body tag.

Your solution may look like this:

```
body.template-login_form #portal-searchbox,
body.template-login_form #portal-breadcrumbs{
    display:none;
}
```

If you really want to hide the both parts only on the home page (plone root) you may extend the selector by `.portaltype-plone-site`.

If you want need some styles only for anonymous user you may also use the `userrole-anonymous` css class.

You need to put these lines of css into the ploneCustom.css.

1. Go to ZMI -> portal_skins -> Click Find tab -> Enter "ploneCustom.css" and search.
2. Click "custimize" button.
3. Add the mentioned css --> Save
4. If your site runs in `production` mode you need to re-merge the css registry (ZMI --> portal_css --> Save) in order to deliver the new css to the browser.

Further you may also check the [plone docs.](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/change-the-font-colors.html)

Comment: I'd do it like that, too, upvote. The security-aspect is even negelectable: Really inhibiting the possibility to search for anonymous is not necessary, if the content-items don't hold the 'published' workflow-state. If items are public, you'd probably want them to be searchable as well ;-)

Comment: @Mathias  thanks for your help, but I don't find where put your code, or view that something moves... I've tried to insert code inside /portal_skins/sunburst_styles/base.css or  ploneCustom.css
Where I've wrong?

Comment: No the ploneCustom.css is fine. I extended the answer with a small howTo. If your site runs in PROD mode you need to manually re-merge the css files in order to get the new css delivered to the browser (also described in the howTo.

Comment: I guess Mathias's answer would work best for you. Another option would be overriding the searchbox and path_bar templates with jbot and check for anonymous users and/or the context. So the search would not even get rendered.

Comment: @Mathias your explanation was very clear, I did everything and it works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jurihand l looked Jbot, very interesting, I'll try it

Comment: @fabiosko Could you accept the answer, so other user will know that the answer helps :-)